# REST Should we treat empty updates as SUCCESS?

Tags: rest, http

Just a question out of curiosity while building RESTful services, how to treat empty diffs on updates?

Say suppose we have an object 'Person' as below while created :

Person {
id : 123,
Firstname : "Foo",
Lastname : "Bar",
Age : "Bar"
}

On updating the details of Person, If client passes empty params for updating person with ID 123, Should server treat this as

1. SUCCESS (Since there is nothing to update) ? or
2. Return SUCCESS (But indicate user that there isn't anything to update) OR
3. Throw BadRequest

What is the most preferred way ?

Comment: I would return a 404 error..

Comment: What do you call update? REST isn't CRUD. Which HTTP method are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

I would go with [422](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes). Check the request before performing the actual update. If there are no update params, exit and return 422.

> **422 Unprocessable Entity**
>
> The request was well-formed but was unable to be followed due to semantic errors.

The resource was found, the url exists, the update was successful (although it didn't do anything) and the request was not malformed, therefor neither 404 or 400 would be right.

You could use 200 OK, but I'd personally use 422 [because 4xx status codes have an extra indication that the client made a 'mistake'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error). And I consider an update request with no params a mistake.

Comment: But just to compare and contrast other entities, the "patch" unix command treats empty diff as success without complaining as error. I know this is different semantics but almost close enough in treating diffs.

Comment: Updating a resource is not quite the same operation as Unix patch. When updating a resource you're not diffing, you're just updating whatever was passed in. There is no diffing in the update process

Comment: Isn't update same as applying a "diff"(modify) to resource ? Essentially both are same. And again, this is just what I feel.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the way you provide the empty hints for the person.

If you use the content with a method `PUT`, the provided content expects to completely replace the resource state. So I think it's not something correct since you expect that nothing occurs. In this case, an error should be returned in the status code and content. I agree with Tim that an error `422` should be used (it's commonly used within Web APIs like the one from Github ;-)). However be aware that this code is part of the WebDAV specification and some REST purists would be prefer a generic error `400` with details within the payload.

If you use a method `PATCH`, it corresponds to a partial update of the resource state. I think that in this case, no error would be returned but nothing would be updated for the resource state.

Perhaps this link could give you additional hints: https://templth.wordpress.com/2014/12/15/designing-a-web-api/.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry